# Apostrophe now cms performance issue

Tags: symfony1, apostrophe-cms

I am playing with a sandbox from Apostrophe now. Each time I clear the cache (symfony cc), it takes about 25 sec. to load any page for the first time. Once cache is recreated it's fine, though. Is it normal?

Comment: Hint: create a script, that loads your index page with wget or curl after clearing the cache. It'll make sure the config cache regeneration is triggered by you, not a visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the application is having to read, parse and generate a lot of files. That's why the cache is there - so that it's faster to run normally.